# How I can retrieve emails and websites from csv files in command line?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, csv

I have many `.csv` files (some converted from `xlsx`), and I am trying to extract emails and websites out of those files.

The data in the files looks like:

```
Daniel,Rose,DR@example.com,http://www.example.com,1234567890
Daniel1,Rose,DR1@example.com,http://www.example.com,1234567890
Daniel2,Rose,DR2@example.com,http://example.com,1234567890
Daniel3,Rose,DR3@example.com,www.example.com,1234567890
Daniel4,Rose,DR4@example.com,1234567890,example.com
```

I just want to extract the emails and the websites with the client in that csv.
The output should look like this:

```
DR@example.com
http://www.example.com 
DR1@example.com
http://www.example.com
DR3@example.co
www.example.com
DR4@example.com
```

Comment: Do all lines have the same number of fields? Can you ever have a comma inside a field (csv allows things like `foo, "bar,baz", foob`)? Will the domain always be the 4th comma-separated field? Will the email always be the 5th? Will it always be the last? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: @terdon yes it is simple csv and no such condition till now.

Comment: Please *[edit]* your question and add this information. Also answer my other questions please.

Comment: Hi Jaffer, what to do with the (similar) items with and without `http://`

Comment: @JacobVlijm We can remove them .. Or can leave it if required. Ultimately, I want to extract from the csv. I can sort in next step or simultaneously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A plain-text based, definitely more verbose python option:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

f = sys.argv[1]; out = sys.argv[2]

with open(out, "wt") as wr:
    with open(f) as read:
        for l in read:
            for s in l.strip().split(","):
                if any(["@" in s, "www" in s, "http" in s]):
                    wr.write(s+"\n")
```

Or, just for fun, a bit more compressed:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

with open(sys.argv[2], "wt") as wr:
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as read:
        [[wr.write(s+"\n") for s in l.strip().split(",") if any(["@" in s, "www" in s, "http" in s])] for l in read]
```

#### To use

- Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `get_stuff.py`
- Run it with the source file and targeted output file as arguments:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/get_stuff.py <input_file> <output_file>
  ```

Result:

```
DR@example.com
http://www.example.com
DR1@example.com
http://www.example.com
DR2@example.com
DR3@example.com
www.example.com
DR4@example.com
```

#### Comparison on time

Interesting to see is that on *smaller* files (like in the example), the `sed` option is faster, but on *bigger* files the python option is faster:

on a file of 150.000 lines:

*sed*

```
real    0m0.073s
user    0m0.068s
sys     0m0.000s
```

*python*

```
real    0m0.046s
user    0m0.044s
sys     0m0.000s
```

On a 10-line file:

*sed*

```
real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

*python*

```
real    0m0.037s
user    0m0.032s
sys     0m0.000s
```

(I should mention I have an ancient box, all times should be shorter on a serious machine)

The idea could be that especially if you need to extract data from many *smaller* files in a loop, use sed, on *bigger* files in a loop, use python.

On a single file, small or big, the difference between `0.073`and `0.046` is totally irrelevant.

---

#### Additionally

Below a version to extract the same data from a whole (plain) directory of files.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import os

dr = sys.argv[1]

def extract(f, out):
    with open(out, "wt") as wr:
        with open(f) as read:
            [[wr.write(s+"\n") for s in l.strip().split(",") if any(
                ["@" in s, "www" in s, "http" in s]
                )] for l in read]

for file in os.listdir(dr):
    f = os.path.join(dr, file); out = os.path.join(dr, "extracted_"+file)
    extract(f, out)
```

From each of the files, the script will create a new file with extracted data. From a file:

```
somefile.csv
```

it will create a second file, named:

```
extracted_somefile.csv
```

Comment: Jacob.. you program is excellent. But can you tell me how I can give multiple input and get respective multiple output?

Comment: @JafferWilson sure, in what way? All in a directory or from multiple arguments?

Comment: There are multiple files. But I can club them in a folder. But the output should come up say like out1.txt, out2.txt. It looks good

Comment: Hi @JafferWilson see edited version.

Answer (score 3):

I feel like your desired output is missing 2 rows?

```
$ sed -r 's|.*,([^,]+@[^0-9]+),.*|\1|' file | tr ',' '\n'
DR@example.com
http://www.example.com
DR1@example.com
http://www.example.com
DR2@example.com
http://example.com
DR3@example.com
www.example.com
DR4@example.com
```

If not, then please clarify.

#### Explanation

- `-r` use ERE
- `s|old|new|` replace `old` with `new`
- `.*,` any characters ending with a comma
- `([^,]+@[^0-9]+),.*` save some non-comma chars before an `@`, then some characters that aren't numbers before a comma - match anything after that so we can discard it
- `\1` backreference to the saved pattern
- `tr ',' '\n'` change the remaining commas into newlines (I resorted to piping to `tr` because the fields aren't consistent, but probably it can be avoided cleverly)

Comment: Let me try it. Hope it works. :) I will be using it to create a bash script so I need not have to convert and operate Excel file.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I can manage to have uniqueness... :P